# How to verify system file change warnings in rkhunter

Tags: rkhunter

When running rkhunter I try to use

```
rkhunter --propupd
```

when it is finished, but once in a while I forget, and the next time it is run I get the inevitable file changed warning for a few files.

Are hashes of Ubuntu's current version of system files posted somewhere to compare with the file I have on my system?

If not, what is the best way to verify that the file was changed as part of an update.